# Matplotlib submodule _subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I was playing with `seaborn` and I found some example of `seaborn` code.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.swarmplot(x=tips["total_bill"])
```

Now I checked the `type` of `ax` and its `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`. Now I understand that `axes` is the submodule of `matplotlib`. But is `_subplots` a submodule of `axes` ? I could not find any information in the documentation I searched. So then `AxesSubplot` would be a class defined inside the submodule `_subplots`. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_subplots` is a submodule of `axes`:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py

It is not supposed to be manipulated, as suggested by its leading underscore.
Looking at the source code, I guess that your `AxesSubplot` is a class created with `subplot_class_factory`.

Comment: But I don't see the name `AxesSubplot`  anywhere inside the `_subplots.py` file

Comment: Probably because this class is dynamically created. I need to check, but it seems that `subplot_class_factory` has this purpose.

Comment: If the class is created dynamically, where does the name `AxesSubplot` come from ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, and the source can be found [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py).

Modules / variables / classes beginning with an underscore (`_`) in python are considered to be private, and are subject to change at any time (hence the lack of documentation). You shouldn't rely on them staying the same and updating matplotlib may break any code using private modules.

Comment: Because `isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axes.Axes)` there is no danger in relying on the fact that an Axes is returned which may be used in all the usual and documented ways.

Comment: So what does this answer want to tell us then, if it's perfectly safe to use this class?

Comment: It is *not* safe to use the reference `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` since that could change at any time. It is safe to use the reference `matplotlib.axes.Axes`.

Comment: But that is not really relevant, since you cannot use this reference, even if you wanted to, because it is created dynamically. I.e. `isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot)` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` is a class created on the fly from a `matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes` and a `matplotlib.axes._subplot.SubplotBase`. (See [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/adaa8e59a8169ae294cddf5522d3cb9d6b8a6ab3/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py#L205) for the lines in the source code that do this.)

For all practical purposes this is just a normal `Axes`

```
print (type(ax))      # <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
print (isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axes.Axes))          # True
print (isinstance(ax, matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase))   # True
```

You may hence refer to the usual [Axes API documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html) to check what to use this for.

Comment: Will check that. Being a beginner, I just find the documentation overwhelming. But will try to go through it.